# java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException

Tags: java, tomcat, tmp, multipartfile

```
 public HttpEntity<?> card(MultipartFile multipartFile, String name) {
        try {
            String jsonData = String.format("{\"active\": true, \"name\": \"%s\", \"watch_lists\": [\"%s\"]}",
                    name, workerWatchList);

            HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
            headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
            headers.set("Authorization", token);
            HttpEntity<String> addCardEntity = new HttpEntity<>(jsonData, headers);
            ResponseEntity<String> addCardResponse = new RestTemplate().exchange(
                    baseUrl + "/cardurl",
                    HttpMethod.POST,
                    addCardEntity,
                    String.class
            );
            if (addCardResponse.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
                JsonNode rootNode = objectMapper.readTree(addCardResponse.getBody());
                // Get the value associated with the "id" key
                String id = String.valueOf(rootNode.get("id"));
                System.out.println(id);
                HttpHeaders faceHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
                faceHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.MULTIPART_FORM_DATA);
                faceHeaders.set("Authorization", token);

                MultiValueMap<String, Object> faceBody = new LinkedMultiValueMap<>();
                faceBody.add("source_photo", multipartFile.getResource());
                faceBody.add("card", id);
                faceBody.add("mf_selector", "biggest");

                HttpEntity<MultiValueMap<String, Object>> addFaceEntity = new HttpEntity<>(faceBody, faceHeaders);
                ResponseEntity<MultiValueMap> addFaceResponse = new RestTemplate().exchange(
                        baseUrl + "/faceurl",
                        HttpMethod.POST,
                        addFaceEntity,
                        MultiValueMap.class);
                if (addFaceResponse.getStatusCode().is2xxSuccessful()) {
                    return ResponseEntity.ok(id);
                } else {
                    return new ResponseEntity<>(addFaceResponse.getBody(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
                }
            } else {
                return new ResponseEntity<>(addCardResponse.getBody(), HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle any other exceptions
            return ResponseEntity.ok("Error: " + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```

My program sometimes works and sometimes stops working.
There is an error in adding multipart file
I get the following error when I run this program:
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: C:\Users\Acer\AppData\Local\Temp\tomcat.8080.12753633009760934525\work\Tomcat\localhost\ROOT\upload_7761731e_ac13_4cc4_8cda_e9c930bf8a50_00000000.tmp

Comment: Can you elaborate more on what's happening in your code and what you are trying to acheive?

Comment: I'm trying to add a picture to the face list on another server, but I can't

Comment: Can you elaborate on that part of how you create MultiPart File ? In my guess, that is the part where you get the file not found exception .